# Drawing a pair of triangular walls for CS50 Mario

Tags: beginner, c, ascii-art

This is my code for the CS50 Mario (more comfortable).
Answers can be found all over the net however I wrote this myself.

I would like to refactor to its maximum potential (just for my own improvement I'm not enrolled or anything).

A quick outline of the code:

Firstly it asks for a valid input of an amount of rows to be built (an integer between 0 and 550) and then builds a Mario wall like this:

```
    #  #
   ##  ##
  ###  ###
```

---

I have chosen to create 2 functions and called them in the `main` function.

Can this be be improved or refactored anymore or is this as good as it gets?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void build_wall(int num_rows);
void get_rows(int n);
int rows = 0;
int spaces = 0;
int bricks = 0;
int main(void)

{
    get_rows(rows);
    build_wall(rows);
}
void get_rows(int n)
{
    do
    {
    printf("How many rows would you like? ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("\n");
    printf("You would like %d rows.\n", rows);
    }
    while (rows <= 0 || rows >=550);
}

void build_wall(int num_rows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++) ///number of rows
    {
        for(spaces = 0; spaces < num_rows-i-1; spaces++ )       // first spaces
            {
                printf(" ");
            }

        for(bricks = 0; bricks < i+1; bricks++)             //   first wall bricks
            {
                printf("#");
            }

        {
            printf("  ");                                   //Middle spaces
        }

        for(bricks = 0; bricks < i+1; bricks++)            // Second wall bricks
            {
                printf("#");
            }
    printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Is https://cs50.harvard.edu/summer/2022/psets/1/mario/less/ the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Global variables are not called for here.

Since it's such a simple program, there isn't a lot of value in pre-declaring your function signatures; just write out the full definitions in order of dependency (`main` last).

I know it's convention, but I'm personally pretty against omitting `return 0` from `main`; it's a matter of consistency.

You do not check the result of your scan to see if the field was successfully read; you should do that.

A higher-performance solution would form the art in memory and then display it with a single print, rather than issuing multiple `printf` calls.

`scanf` is pretty broken; I'll leave you to Google. Below I show one method that is roughly sane.

### Suggested

Here is one approach. Since you don't want to right-fill spaces, buffer size calculation requires a bit of geometry whose rationale I will leave as an exercise to the reader.

Compile with this example makefile:

```
export

cflags=-std=c18 -Wall -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L

all: mario

mario: main.o
    gcc $$cflags -o $@ $<

%.o: %.c makefile
    gcc $$cflags -o $@ $< -c

clean:
    rm -f *.o mario
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// For https://cs50.harvard.edu/summer/2022/psets/1/mario/less/


static const int max_rows = 550, n_spaces = 2;


static size_t get_rows()
{
    size_t n_rows;
    for (;;)
    {
        printf("How many rows would you like? ");
        
        // POSIX only - https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html
        char *buffer = NULL;
        size_t size = 0;
        if (getline(&buffer, &size, stdin) < 1) {
            free(buffer);
            continue;
        }
        
        char *end;
        n_rows = strtoul(buffer, &end, 10);
        free(buffer);
        
        if (end == buffer)
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid number\n");
        else if (n_rows > 0 && n_rows <= max_rows)
            return n_rows;
        fprintf(stderr, "Number out of range\n");
    }
}


static char *allocate_wall(int n_rows, int *n_chars)
{
    // left hashes, spaces, right hash, newline
    int xmin = n_rows + n_spaces + 1 + 1;
    
    // left and right hashes, spaces, newline
    int xmax = 2*n_rows + n_spaces + 1;
    
    *n_chars = (xmax*(xmax + 1) - xmin*(xmin-1))/2;
    
    // all printable characters then a null terminator
    int size = *n_chars + 1;
    
    char *buffer = malloc(size);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate buffer\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    return buffer;
}


static void fill_wall(char *buffer, int n_rows, int n_chars)
{   
    // Start by filling with #, which is the most abundant character in the output
    memset(buffer, '#', n_chars);
    
    char *pwrite = buffer;
    
    for (int y = 0; y < n_rows; y++)
    {
        int leading_spaces = n_rows - y - 1;
        memset(pwrite, ' ', leading_spaces);
        pwrite += leading_spaces;
        
        int brick_width = y + 1;
        pwrite += brick_width;
        
        memset(pwrite, ' ', n_spaces);
        pwrite += n_spaces + brick_width;
        
        *pwrite = '\n';
        pwrite++;
    }
    
    // Terminating null
    buffer[n_chars] = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
    int n_rows = get_rows();
    
    int n_chars;
    char *buffer = allocate_wall(n_rows, &n_chars);
    
    fill_wall(buffer, n_rows, n_chars);
    
    printf(buffer);
    
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

For giggles: adding `-Ofast -march=native`, increasing `max_rows`, putting 10000 into `large-size` and then

```
time ./mario < large-size > /dev/null
```

takes about 0.1 seconds to allocate, format and output 150,035,000 bytes of data. Under the same conditions, the original code takes about 2.715 seconds.

Comment: May I ask for an example? It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There you are - it will require some follow-up reading

Comment: Many thanks, that gives me plenty to research and get on with- greatly appreciated.